# How to determine if 2 different words have the same letters?

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, arraylist

I have a word list that has all the words in the dictionary and I am supposed to use the list to find if any inputted word has the same characters as others.

What I tried was using the Arrays.sort() method to alphabetize every word and the input word then use the .equals() method to compare the 2 strings. Then print the instance where .equals() is true.

However, when I do this, the output just prints every word in the list and I am not sure why.

Edit for clarity : the idea is to determine the words in the list that match the input.
For example: if I enter act, all words with the letters a,c, and t would be the output. In this case the only output would be cat.

Comment: Show us the code.

Comment: As in a jumbled word?  So would `tea` also match `eat`?

Comment: This question is not particularly clear. I'm not sure why the downvote on my answer, but if that doesn't suit what you're looking for, please edit your question so we know what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question isn't really clear, but I'll provide a solution that's different from others I've seen:

You can also use list `removeAll` to compare common letters between two lists...

```
listA.removeAll(listB); //listA will contain any letters not common to listB
if (listA.size() == 0) {
    return true; 
}
```

Test output:

```
apppppppleeeeeeee <-- Input
[a, p, p, p, p, p, p, p, l, e, e, e, e, e, e, e, e] //String split 1
[a, p, p, l, e] //String split 2
letters are the same

appleeeeeef <-- Input
[a, p, p, l, e, e, e, e, e, e, f]
[a, p, p, l, e]
contains different letters
```

---

**Code:**

```
public class Main {

    public Main () {
        Scanner scan;
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scan.nextLine(); 
        if(check(split(input), split("apple"))) {
            System.out.println("letters are the same");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("contains different letters");
        }
    }

    public boolean check(ArrayList<String> listA, ArrayList<String> listB) {
        listA.removeAll(listB); //listA will contain any letters not common to listB
        if (listA.size() == 0) 
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> split(String word) {
        String[] splitMe = word.split("(?!^)");
        ArrayList<String> splitList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < splitMe.length; i++) {
            splitList.add(splitMe[i]);  
        }
        System.out.println(splitList);
        return splitList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple algorithm to find out if two words share the same letters:

1. sort the letters in each word
2. alphabetize the results
3. look for duplicates

This only shows existence of anagrams, of course. To return a list of anagrams is a little more work. 
One way to do it would be to make a Map where your keys are the sorted words (that is, the characters in each word have been sorted) and the values are lists of words which have those letters.

Example (code not tested, for illustration only):

```
Map <String, List<String>> anagrams = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
for (String s:inputList)
{
  key = sort(s); // returns s as String, chars sorted, trivial
  if (anagrams.get(key) == null)
  { 
    anagrams.put(key, new LinkedList<String>());
  }
  anagrams.get(key).add (s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>   String lst[] = {"asd","qwe","zxc"}; 
>   System.out.println(Arrays.asList(lst).contains("assd"));
> ```